# Docker Compose Dev and Production Environments Best Workflow

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile, docker-compose

I've built a simple Docker Compose project as a development environment. I have PHP-FPM, Nginx, MongoDB, and Code containers.
Now I want to automate the process and deploy to production.
The `docker-compose.yml` can be extended and can define multiple environments. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/ for more information.
However, there are Dockerfiles for my containers. And for the dev environment are needed more packages than in production.

The main question is should I use separate dockerfiles for `dev` and `prod` and manage them in `docker-compose.yml` and `production.yml` ?
Separate dockerfiles are easy approach but there is code duplication.

The other solution is to use environment variables and somehow handle them from bash script (maybe as entrypoint ?).

I am searching for other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/):

> ... you’ll probably want to define a separate Compose file, say
>   `production.yml`, which specifies production-appropriate configuration.
>
> Note: The `extends` keyword is useful for maintaining multiple Compose
>   files which re-use common services without having to manually copy and
>   paste.

Comment: Yes, I did but I still have to install some packages for dev and prod environments and this is done in Dockerfile. But dockerfiles doesn't have control structures like other languages so you can't control what to install depending on the environment.

Comment: in that case, you might want to consider using ansible. it works like this: use a Dockerfile just to bootstrap the image with ansible, then let ansible take over. If you want to go all the way and automate everything then, you would start with ansible playbooks to create Docker images on your local machine; then push them to a private (or public) registry (also run within docker :) then write ansible playbooks to fetch those images on remote hosts and start containers

Comment: That could be solved by having separate Dockerfiles for development and production (I guess you could have a common base as well).

Answer (score 1):

In `docker-compose` version >= 1.5.0 you can use [environment variables](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/129092b7/docs/yml.md#variable-substitution), may be this suits you?

Answer (score 1):

If the packages needed for development aren't too heavy (i.e. the image size isn't significally bigger) you could just create `Dockerfile`s that include all the components and then decide whether to activate them based on the value of an environment variable in the entrypoint.

That way you would could have the main `docker-compose.yml` providing the *production* environment while `development.yml` would just add the correct environment variable value where needed.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation it might be worth considering using an "onbuild" image to handle the commonalities among environments, then using separate images to handle the specifics. Some official images have onbuild versions, e.g., [Node](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/718102a587e7f02748402551b51407332384c1b3/6.9/onbuild/Dockerfile). Or you can create your own.